# C# and Processing socket communication

Tags: c#, sockets, processing

I am trying to develop a software (in C#) that collect some data on a list (`List<string> socketList`). The value of this list must be sent to a processing software. 
In this program, the server (the C# software) waits for a message from a client (the Processing software) and send an element of the list. This list is continuously filled by a method in another thread (I verify, the list is everytime full). I used this method because I need that each value has to arrive at a client, no matter the speed.
Here there is the method in C# (it is launched as a thread):

```
public static void InizializeSocket()
{
    //setting the comunication port
    int port = 5000;

    //infinite loop in order to accept sequential clients
    while (true)
    {
        //I open the listener for any IP
        TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port);
        Console.WriteLine("Listening...");

        //Waiting for a client
        listener.Start();
        TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
        Console.WriteLine("CONNECTED");

        //this string will contain the client message
        String dataReceived = "";

        //loop until "q". If the client send a message with a q, the server disconnect the client
        while (dataReceived != "q")
        {
            //Read the client message
            NetworkStream nwStream = client.GetStream();
            try
            {
                //Define the client message buffer dimension and read the message
                byte[] buffer = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
                int bytesRead = nwStream.Read(buffer, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);
                //Encoding the byte in a string
                dataReceived = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

                //check if the List<string> socketList is not empty. If it has any elements, I send the first one and after that I remove the element from the list
                if (socketList.Count > 0)
                {
                    //Encoding the string in a byte
                    byte[] bytesToSend = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(socketList[0]);
                    nwStream.Write(bytesToSend, 0, bytesToSend.Length);
                    socketList.RemoveAt(0);
                }
                nwStream.Flush();
            }
            catch (Exception e) { dataReceived = "q"; }
        }
        //Exit from the client loop
        Console.WriteLine("DISCONNECTED");
        client.Close();
        listener.Stop();
    }
}
```

And here the simple Processing software

```
import processing.net.*; 

Client myClient; 
String dataIn;
int port = 5000;
String ip = "127.0.0.1";

void setup () {
size(1100, 1025); 
//Initialize the client
  myClient = new Client(this, "127.0.0.1", 5000);   
}


void draw () {
    //If the client is available it send a generic message to the server and try to receive a response
   if (myClient.available() > 0) { 
    myClient.write("c");
    dataIn = myClient.readString();
  } 
  //print the output in debug
 println(dataIn);
}
```

Here the Processing software is able to connect, anyway, I received every time `null`.

In addition, if I try to write (in the try on the C# software) only:

```
if (socketList.Count > 0)
{
    byte[] bytesToSend = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(socketList[0]);
    nwStream.Write(bytesToSend, 0, bytesToSend.Length);
    socketList.RemoveAt(0);

}
```

I receive strange values that are not the same values in the list stored in C# software.

So, why in the first case processing read only `null` value? And why in the second case it read "random" value?

EDIT:
Analyze better the programs flow, I verify where is the problem. I rewrite the processing socket as a java socket. It is launched in another thread and fills an ArrayList. 
Considering a simplification of the code (in order to understand better), if I write:

```
  Socket s = new Socket("localhost", 5000);
  BufferedReader input =new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
  PrintWriter out=  new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(), true);
  out.println("hello");
  String temp = input.readLine();
```

the software blocks on `String temp = input.readLine();`. Anyway, the communication is established and I am sure that C# send the string.

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: Consider using WCF instead of writing your own communication layer.

Comment: It's hard to make sense of your code. Your sending a string over the socket -- can you explain how it's encoded? How is the end of the string marked?

Comment: I am sorry, give to me a couple of minutes and I comment the code. Anyway, the string are not end marked (it is a simple string)

Comment: I add the comments in the code :)

Comment: @youngz I recommend giving OSC a go.In C# you can use [SharpOSC](https://github.com/ValdemarOrn/SharpOSC) and in Processing you can use [oscP5](http://www.sojamo.de/libraries/oscP5/)